# Question regarding stars and bars problem

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following problem : For the natural numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3$, count the number of solutions to the equation: $$x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} =15\,,$$ such that : $$1 \leq x_1 \leq 6  $$ $$1 \leq x_2 \leq 4 $$ After using the stars and bars method , I get that the total number of solutions is $25$ . However when I run the numbers through a program that calculates the number of solutions , I get that the total number of solutions should be $24$ . To find the number $25$ , I calculated the total number of solutions without any restrictions , and then I subtracted the number of solutions where $x_1\ge7$ and $x_2\ge5$. Can you tell me what I did wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you used stars and bars first? FWIW, the PIE approach that you used later is the "right" way to do deal with this.  $\quad$ Note: The answer should be 24.

Comment: To calculate the total number of solutions without any restrictions , i used C(17,15) . I got that the total number of solutions is 136 . Then i calculated the solutions with the first restriction ( x1 <= 6 ) , in which i used C(10,8) , where i got 45 . Then i did the same for x2 , using C(12,10) , where i got 66 . I subtracted both 45 and 66 from 136 which gave me 25. I don't get why the answer should be 24.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that your ${17\choose15}=136$ includes solutions with one or more of the $x_i$ being zero, and you never excluded those.

The second problem is that when you subtract the number with $x_1\ge7$ and the number with $x_2\ge5$, you have to add back in the ones you've excluded twice, the ones with both $x_1\ge7$ and $x_2\ge5$.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer without changing  the way the problem was presented*

If you want to do it without changing the way the problem has been presented, you first have to use the formula where the variables are positive integers [Theorem 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#:%7E:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20combinatorial,his%20classic%20book%20on%20probability.), viz $\large\binom{n-1}{k-1}$and then apply inclusion-exclusion.

So the process is
[Total ways]
- [$x_1$ over limit]
- [$x_2$ over limit]
+ [both $x_1$ and $x_2$ over limit]

$$=\binom{14}2-\binom82 - \binom{10}2 +\binom42 = {24}$$